# Grouping a set of values into minimum number of buckets so that the sum of values within each bucket does not exceed a limit value.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization

I am trying to find the minimum number of buckets (g) needed to group a set of values [n1, n2, n3,...], in such a way that the sum of the values in each bucket doesn't exceed a certain limit value (l).

Assume that all values (n), are less than or equal the limit value (l).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: This is the well-known bin packing problem.

Comment: [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).